# fatal error: opencv2/photo.hpp OpenCV 3.0 install

Tags: ubuntu, installation, opencv3.0

I am compiling, from source, a branch of the artoolkit which relies on OpenCV 3.0. The OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

When i run make it reports this error.....

'fatal error: opencv2/photo.hpp: No such file or directory"

In Ubuntu....

I have usr/local/include/opencv2 which contains core.hpp etc. However there is no module for photo.hpp.

I have attempted to install opencv 3.0 a few times after purging all the opencv2 files in the include folders.

How do i link to this file?

Regards,

Daniel

P.S.

This is a repeat of a questions posted on Opencv Answers that has not recieved any attention.

http://answers.opencv.org/question/86515/fatal-error-opencv2photohpp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` from the terminal

the header file `photo.hpp` is found in `/usr/indlude/opencv2/photo`

The Makefile you have is searching for this header in `/usr/include/opencv2` which is one level above where `apt` has installed it so you need to put a symlink in that directory which points to the correct location.  Type this into your terminal

```
cd /usr/include/opencv2
sudo ln -s /usr/include/opencv2/photo/photo.hpp photo.hpp
```

then run `make` again and it should compile